# How to understand the increase of charge density in a moving frame?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Suppose I have a infinite long neutral wire with current $I$, which is at rest. Now I run parallel to the wire with velocity $u$. We know that by relativity, the charge density in my frame is no longer zero.

My confusion comes out: We didn't create or destroy any charge. How to understand the increase in charge density?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the worldlines of the electrons (in motion, say with $v=0.25c$ for convenience) and the protons (at rest) in Alice's frame where the wire is neutral. Let's draw this on a spacetime diagram on rotated graph paper.

[image: charge density on rotated graph paper]

Let's calculate the charge densities along a convenient segment along Alice's x-axis, say along OX.
$$\rho_{A,+}=\frac{+10Q}{10\rm\ m}\qquad\rho_{A,-}=\frac{-10Q}{10\rm\ m}\qquad\rho_{A,net}=\frac{0Q}{10\rm\ m}.$$

Suppose Bob moves with velocity $v=0.8c$ (so $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}=5/3$) for convenience.
Let's calculate the charge densities along a convenient segment along Bob's x-axis, say along OL.
$$\rho_{B,+}=\frac{+10Q}{6\rm\ m}\qquad\rho_{B,-}=\frac{-8Q}{6\rm\ m}\qquad\rho_{B,net}=\frac{+2Q}{6\rm\ m}.$$
(The ratio 6/10 ($=\frac{1}{\gamma}$) arises from length-contraction.)

Comment: This is a beautiful intuitive picture of how fields transform

Comment: Thanks... but there are no fields here... just particle worldlines and the "light-clock diamonds" of each inertial observer. (My student and I are actually working on how to show how the electromagnetic field transform.)

Comment: Ok sorry for the semantics - a great picture of *why* the fields transform.

Comment: @robphy could you share those pictures with us about electromagnetic fields transformations would be awesome and great help to our intuition

Comment: @Mahin My student and I are working on the visualization, but we have many cases to work out analytically. (It's been an on-and-off research project of mine since graduate school.) Hopefully, it will mesh well with the light-clock diamond representation.

Comment: @robphy would it be possible when you have finished your work to show us the result you achieved